# Get all packet(uint) from byte array

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, tlv

I am working on one BLE project
I am getting following data(In Byte array while scanning BLE device) as an advertising data 0x02011A09094F6E65506C757332020AF9 you can see in the screenshot there is three packet, can anyone help me how can get all three packet by java code.

[image]

Comment: ????? If you get 0x02011A09094F6E65506C757332020AF9 then you have all three already. What is the problem?

Answer (score 2):

You can try this :

```
public SparseArray<byte[]> parseAdvertisingData(byte[] rawData) {
    final SparseArray<byte[]> parsedData = new SparseArray<>();
    for (int index = 0; index < rawData.length; ) {
        final byte dataLength = rawData[index++];
        if (dataLength == 0) {
            break;
        }

        final int dataType = rawData[index];
        if (dataType == 0) {
            break;
        }

        byte[] data = Arrays.copyOfRange(rawData, index + 1, index + dataLength);
        parsedData.put(dataType, data);

        index += dataLength;
    }
    return parsedData;
}
```

Here is a simple example:

```
final byte[] rawData = Utils.parseHexBinary("02011A09094F6E65506C757332020AF9");
final SparseArray<byte[]> parsed = parseAdvertisingData(rawData);
for (int i = 0; i < parsed.size(); i++) {
    final int type = parsed.keyAt(i);
    final byte[] data = parsed.valueAt(i);

    Log.d(TAG, String.format("type: 0x%02x, value: 0x%s", type,
            new BigInteger(1, data).toString(16)));
}
```

result:

```
type: 0x01, value: 0x1a
type: 0x09, value: 0x4f6e65506c757332
type: 0x0a, value: 0xf9
```